# Running Tensorflow on JupyterNotebook instead of on Terminal commands

Tags: tensorflow, terminal, jupyter-notebook

I wish to run [some Tensorflow code](https://github.com/davidsandberg/facenet/wiki/Validate-on-LFW) on JupyterNotebook.

If run it on terminal, then the link above gives instructions like this:

```sh
python src/validate_on_lfw.py ~/datasets/lfw/lfw_mtcnnpy_160 ~/models/facenet/20170512-110547
```

**Question: how do I run it on Jupyter notebook ?** Thanks
e.g.,

```py
# Load the model
facenet.load_model(args.model)
```

Simply replace `args.model` with `~/models/facenet/20170512-110547`

```py
# Load the model
facenet.load_model('~/models/facenet/20170512-110547')
```

will give error

```py
usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [-h] [--lfw_batch_size LFW_BATCH_SIZE]
                             [--image_size IMAGE_SIZE] [--lfw_pairs LFW_PAIRS]
                             [--lfw_file_ext {jpg,png}]
                             [--lfw_nrof_folds LFW_NROF_FOLDS]
                             lfw_dir model
ipykernel_launcher.py: error: too few arguments

sys.argv
Out[5]:
['/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py',
 '-f',
 '/Users/my_name/Library/Jupyter/runtime/kernel-770c12c9-8fbe-44f7-91dd-4b0a5c5d7537.json']
```

Comment: What is the error that you get? And share the code?

Comment: revised to add error. I am doing in a very Adhoc way...

Comment: It seems like you didn't launch the jupyter notebook. First launch the notebook and then run the commands.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, simple solution...
Simply run it on Terminal as the given GitHub suggested and in the mean time print out the sys.argv on terminal like this

```
    sys.argv = ['src/validate_on_lfw.py', '/Users/../datasets/lfw/lfw_mtcnnpy_160', '/Users/../models/facenet/20170512-110547']
```

Then use these values of sys.argv in JupyterNotebook in `def parse_arguments(argv)` as default values, and it worked